# when opening Main.axml in visual studio it is showing the below error CreateSession failed due to an internal error?

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin

### I have installed xamarin for visual studio manually,and path for sdk,ndk,jdk has been configured correctly but still iam getting this error

No indirect rendering available
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class com.android.sdklib.repository.targets.SystemImage

at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSysImgPkgInfo.extractTagFromProps(LocalSysImgPkgInfo.java:88)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSdk.scanSysImages(LocalSdk.java:1035)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.local.LocalSdk.getPkgsInfos(LocalSdk.java:552)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.legacy.LegacyLocalRepoLoader.parseLegacyLocalPackage(LegacyLocalRepoLoader.java:100)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.parsePackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:176)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.LocalRepoLoaderImpl.getPackages(LocalRepoLoaderImpl.java:154)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl$LoadTask.run(RepoManagerImpl.java:653)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager$DummyProgressRunner.runSyncWithProgress(RepoManager.java:398)
    at com.android.repository.impl.manager.RepoManagerImpl.load(RepoManagerImpl.java:387)
    at com.android.repository.api.RepoManager.loadSynchronously(RepoManager.java:290)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler$RepoConfig.createRepoManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:695)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getSdkManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:269)
    at com.android.sdklib.repository.AndroidSdkHandler.getAndroidTargetManager(AndroidSdkHandler.java:307)
    at mono.android.AndroidDesignerHost.getAndroidTarget(AndroidDesignerHost.java:86)
    at mono.android.DesignerSession.initialize(DesignerSession.java:114)
    at mono.android.Project.createSession(Project.java:383)
    at mono.android.Project.processMessage(Project.java:414)
    at mono.android.MessageListener.executeMessage(MessageListener.java:88)
    at mono.android.MessageListener$Runner.run(MessageListener.java:44)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

[please see here for the  photo snipet of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aOOBS.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

after a big headmarch of approx 15 days it all solved just by changing the system default language to English. (my system default language was Hindi) .